# What is the name of "?" operator/symbol in "var button: Button? = null" expression in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

We can define a variable considering whether it can store a null value or not by using the `?` operator at the end of the variable's type, such as `var button: Button? = null`.

I know that when we will be using the *button* variable we have to use the safe call operator `?.`, but that is different from the operator we used in  `var button: Button? = null`

Now, how should I pronounce this `?` operator?

Comment: This is not really an operator, it doesn't have a name. This is a part of the type system, but you know this already.

Comment: Interesting fact: when used as a type modifier, `?` seems to be parsed as a separate token. (So you can separate it with whitespace, e.g. `Int ?`. I never knew that until I tried it just now! And I certainly _wouldn't_ recommend it…) That probably doesn't make it an operator as such, but it's different from `as?`, `?.`, and `?:`, which _are_ single, indivisible operators, separate from unadorned `as` and `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it the "nullable/nullability operator". In the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator), you find some references to it (associated with other operators, like `as`), **although it might not have an official name**.

> "Safe" (nullable) cast operator

In the [Keyworks and Operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols) section in the documentation, you will find a reference to it as:

> ? marks a type as nullable

Comment: The term "safe cast operator" refers to the whole operator `as?`, not the `?` by itself. `?` after a type is simply part of the type. It doesn't perform an operation, so it isn't an operator. I would call it *nullability symbol*, although it doesn't seem to have an official name.

Comment: Yeah, I know but the difference in the name for the non-safe `as` is just the "nullable" part, so I think it is fair to call it "nullable/nullability operator". But then again as I wrote it does not seem to have an official name as the second part of my answer shows.

Comment: It's a meta operator. It operates on operators. :)

Comment: That is true ;)

Comment: @Tenfour04 While insightful and amusing, I'm not convinced that calling it a ‘meta-operator’ is necessarily going to help folks who aren't already familiar with this stuff :-)